# HSSFRow getCell() method returning date value in different format

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm reading xls values from two files and comparing them. The problem is with the second file, 
When I use this code - 
`HSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(columnIndex);`

I have to read this date from one cell - **2018-11-25** but it's reading it as **25-Nov-2018** which is wrong.
//ly, with the same code if I'm reading this date 
Jun 29, 2018 09:25:41 AM -> it's reading as -> 29-Jun-2018

**How can I fix this and get the value as it is??**
After this code - I'm checking if cell2 is numeric I'll compare the dates so it's going inside if and failing there.

```
HSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(columnIndex);
switch (cell2.getCellTypeEnum()) {
        case NUMERIC: {
            if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell2)) {
            if (!c1.equals(cell2.toString())) {
                equalCellValues = false;
            }
        }
        }

After reading this date "2018-11-25"
Actual Result - 25-Nov-2018 (I'm getting now)
Expected Result - 2018-11-25 (should be same as there in the file)
```

Comment: I don't see any date in your code

Comment: @YCF_L when I'm reading the value from excel cell, in the xls file cell - "2018-11-25" is the value. row2.getCell(columnIndex); it is pointing to this date cell and reading wrong as 25-Nov-2018

Comment: Do using `apache poi`'s [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html): 
`...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
...
Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(columnIndex);
String formattedCellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell2);`

Comment: @AxelRichter With that I'm able to get  2018-11-25 instead of 25-Nov-2018 but now the xls cell Jun 29, 2018 09:25:41 AM is read as 2018-06-29 09:25:41 AM which is a failure

Comment: This exactly is the reason why I have not put that in an answer. You do not provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So we cannot reproduce your issues and that's why all we can do is wild guessing.

Comment: @AxelRichter My only issue is I have to read cell values from xls. They can be date also. So, if my cell has 2018-11-25 -> its reading as -> 25-Nov-2018 while its reading Jun 29, 2018 09:25:41 AM -> as same only -> Jun 29, 2018 09:25:41 AM............. And if I try your solution then it's coming as 2018-11-25 ->2018-11-25 and its coming as Jun 29, 2018 09:25:41 AM -> 2018-06-29 09:25:41 AM

Comment: Yes, that have you told already. But when I do the same, using `DataFormatter`, then my results are exactly as shown in `Excel`. So to be able reproducing your issue, we would need the `Excel` file in question.

Comment: I have created a sample file u can download the file from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L5WpBz_qUfur9IhrMDlnMl63QvSP0MPc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Nothing in your `Excel` sheet is really a date. All cell contents are text. And when I read the cell contents using `DataFormatter` all comes exactly as in `Excel`. So, sorry, your issue is not reproducible for me.